# Passing Data from javascript to HTML tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize

I want to select and pass the data of a row from a dynamically generated table to a modal to visualize.

Bellow is what I've tried:

#### Javascript:

```
function getDataFromRow(obj) {
  var modal = document.getElementById("modal1");

  var oTable = document.getElementById('myTableData'); // gets table

  var index = obj.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex; // gets index of clicked row

  var oCells = oTable.rows.item(index).cells; // gets cells of current row

  var cellLength = oCells.length; // gets amount of cells of current row

  // loops through each cell in current row
  for(var j = 2; j < cellLength; j++){
    var cellVal = oCells.item(j).innerHTML; // get your cell info here

    $( ".ModalText").append('<div>' + cellVal + '</div>');
  }
}
```

#### HTML code of Modal:

```
<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div class="modal" id="modal1">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Modal Header</h4>
    <div class="ModalText"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat ">Close</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Code of my table HTML:

```
 <table id="myTableData" class="bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><b>Name</b></td>
          <td><b>Species_Id</b></td>
          <td><b>Name</b></td>
          <td><b>Species_Id</b></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
```

#### JQuery of my table HTML:

```
var obj = text;
for(var i = 0;  i < obj.features.length; i++) {
var featureTitle = obj.features[i].properties.title;
var featureHab = obj.features[i].properties.Broad_Habi;
var timestamp = obj.features[i].properties.timestamp;
var id = obj.features[i].properties.id;
var coordinatesx = obj.features[i].properties.geom_X;
var coordinatesy = obj.features[i].geometry.geom_Y;
var image = obj.features[i].properties.Image;
var name = obj.features[i].geometry.Name;

$('#myTableData tbody').append(
'<tr><td><a class="btn-floating btn-smal waves-effect waves-light"><i data-  target="modal1" class="btn-floating modal-trigger small material-icons onClick="Javacsript:getDataFromRow(this)">info_outline</i></a></td>'+
    '<td><a class="btn-floating btn-smal waves-effect waves-light"><i class="btn-floating small material-icons" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow(this)">delete</i></a></td>'+
    '<td><img src ="' + image + '"class="responsive-img"></td>'+
                                '<td>'+id+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+featureTitle+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+timestamp+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+coordinatesx+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+coordinatesy+'</td>'+
                                '</tr>');
```

Comment: Did you forget the closing bracket for your function only here?

Comment: Yes i forgot it only here

Comment: @Ben : Just fixed that for ya ;-)

Comment: Thanks John ;) can you also help me with my question ?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific what you mean by "visualize" the data in the modal?

Comment: @Ben you can use js function just like the way you get the data to write them. Use jQuery methods in order to achieve it with less code. First you must create the output in variable and then append it to the modal's element <p>.

Comment: The data only needs to be written as text in the modal

Comment: As @burningLights suggested be more specific . The way you parse your table won't work. Also provide your html table in your question to further help us understand what you mean.

Comment: @JmRag  I added the code for my table which is working fine. If the info button of the specified row is clicked i want to visualize the data from my table inside the modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean in the jQuery section but here's an example of what I assume you want to do:

First you parse everything in the td of the table and store it in a variable:

```
 var output="";
    //parse everything in a td of this table and store it in a variable
    $("table#myTableData td").each(function(){
     //parse each cell of the table and append it's content to a variable
      output=output+" "+$(this).html();

    });
```

Then append this variable to the element you want:

```
$('#modal1 p').html(output);
```

Here is a working copy of the way I am suggesting

https://plnkr.co/edit/OsiTBcw8JrjwZZGWkulu?p=preview

I wrapped it all to a function that is triggered on click of a button

---

here is another example on how to use jQuery in the same logic as the above to parse the elements of the row where the button is located.

https://plnkr.co/edit/NLUZCbTNmkbyK5YPTCgC?p=preview

I know it's may be confusing on how to traverse the DOM with jQuery but once you familiarize with it it's a piece of cake.

---

The $(document).ready() function is called when the html is done rendering so you should include all your logic in there.

The $('button').click(function) {..} is triggered when a user click's on that button.

jQuery selectors work the same way as css selectors do.

Also you may find usefull to read this page: 
https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/
about how you can use jQuery to parse the DOM according to your needs. The examples are very good.

Comment: Thanks you very much. Can you maybe tell me how i have to embed this in my code. Unfortunately i am really new to this.

Comment: @Ben You wrap the code in a js file. E.g. script.js and you include the file in your html. Read carefully every line in my plunker example and you will figure it out. Don't hesitate to experiment with it

Comment: @Ben You're welcome I update my answer with some more explaining you might need.